# Does Talend's tRedshiftUnload component support IAM roles?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data ( Version 6.4.1 ) to UNLOAD a dataset from Amazon Redshift to S3. The UNLOAD operation works fine when S3 Access Key and Secret Key are provided.

Is there a way to include the IAM role ARN instead of S3 Access Key and Secret Key to perform this UNLOAD operation since that is supported by Redshift and is the recommended approach ? I was unable to find a place to specify IAM ARN instead of Secret Key and Access Key in tRedshiftUnload component. Is there a different approach in Talend to achieve the same if tRedshiftUnload does not support it? I would appreciate if you could explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use the first method. (S3 access Key's)

To answer your question No it doesn't however you can use TredshiftRow to execute an unload directly on the database for more information see the below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html